# Using ConfigurationProperties to build Java POJO Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have below some of the properties in the HashMap as key value pair

```
topic1.topicname =testTopic1
topic1.listenerid=id1
topic1.max.poll.records=5
topic2.topicname =testTopic2
topic2.listenerid=id2
topic2.max.poll.records=5
```

And I want to convert the above key value pair into java pojo configuration properties as below

```
Map<String, CustomKafkaListenerProperty> props;
```

with key as topic1 and topic2, and value as corresponding CustomKafkaListenerProperty pojo

the attributes in CustomKafkaListenerProperty Pojo as below

```
private String topicname;
private String listenerId;
private String maxPollRecords;
```

Need help on how to do this with spring @ConfigurationProperties

Answer (score 2):

If you can "prepend something" in front of your properties *and* "flatten" `max.poll.records` like:

```
foo.bar.topic1.topicname =testTopic1
foo.bar.topic1.listenerid=id1
foo.bar.topic1.max-poll-records=5
foo.bar.topic2.topicname =testTopic2
foo.bar.topic2.listenerid=id2
foo.bar.topic2.max-poll-records=5
```

Then (it's a 14-liner,) we can model them like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class MyProperties { // must be public! regarding constructors, read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding

  Map<String, CustomKafkaListenerProperty> bar;

}
```

..and:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class CustomKafkaListenerProperty { // can be non: pulic/static/nested
    String topicname;
    String listenerId;
    String maxPollRecords;
}
```

... enable them:

```
@SpringBootApplication
// when they are in a custom file: @PropertySource(("classpath:/com/example/some.properties"))
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
public class SpringApp { ...
```

So the test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SpringAppTests { 

  @Autowired
  MyProperties props;

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
    System.out.println(props);
    assertNotNull(props);
  }
}
```

...will pass! ...and give us following  output:

```
MyProperties(bar={
  topic2 = MyProperties.CustomKafkaListenerProperty(topicname=testTopic2, listenerId=id2, maxPollRecords=5),
  topic1 = MyProperties.CustomKafkaListenerProperty(topicname=testTopic1, listenerId=id1, maxPollRecords=5)}
)
```

(originally unformatted)

Problems:

- We *have to* pre-pend the properties as they are. (i see no other way (yet))
- We *have to* change `max.poll.records` to `max-poll-records` (kebab-case).